# In beginner scheme how do I represent a variable as a string?

Tags: scheme, racket

My question is how do i code for

```
(triangle 5) produces (list "*****" "****" "***" "**" "*")
```

Note: (5 astericks 4, then 3 then 2 then 1). So far I have:

```
(define (triangle n)
  (cond
    [(zero? n) empty]
    [else (cons n (triangle (sub1 n)))]))
```

But that only gives me `(list 5 4 3 2 1)`. Please keep note that this uses only the basic of scheme beginner lists and abbreviations. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's always a good idea to split a complex problem in simpler, shorter subparts. In this case, we can simplify the general solution by first writing solutions to subproblems, like this:

1. First, build a procedure that creates a list of strings, where a string is `"*****"` or `"****"` or ... or `"*"`
2. Second, write a `repeat` helper procedure that given a string and a number, repeats the string that many times - for example: `(repeat "*" 3)` will return `"***"`

It's easy to see how the first subproblem can be expressed in terms of the second one. Because this looks like a homework, you shouldn't be asking for complete solutions here. It'll be more useful for you to reach the answer by yourself, here's the general idea, fill-in the blanks:

```
(define (triangle n)
  (cond [<???> <???>]                 ; if n is zero return the empty list: '()
        [else                         ; otherwise
         (cons <???>                  ; cons n repetitions of * (using `repeat`)
               (triangle <???>))]))   ; and advance the recursion

(define (repeat str n)
  (cond [<???> <???>]                 ; if n is zero return the empty string: ""
        [else                         ; otherwise
         (string-append <???>         ; append the given string
             (repeat <???> <???>))])) ; and advance the recursion
```

If you look at it carefully, both procedures share exactly the same structure. What changes is the value returned in the base case (an empty list and an empty string) and the procedure used for sticking together the partial answers (`cons` and `string-append`).

Comment: Thanks for your help! So far I have solved both those parts but now I'm drawing a blank on how to incorporate repeat so that the code can turn from (list 5 4 3 2 1) to (list the asterisks)

Comment: There's an error in the code you posted in the question. You must not do this: `(cons n (triangle (sub1 n))`, that'll return a list of numbers. Instead of the `n`, call the helper procedure with the right parameters

Comment: I tried to correct it to 

(define (triangle n)
  (cond
    [(zero? (num-to-stars n)) empty]
    [else (cons (num-to-stars n (triangle (sub1 n))))]))
but it gives me an error saying it expected 1 but got 2 arguments

Comment: @JamesLalonde my pleasure! please don't forget to accept this answer, (by clicking on the check mark to its left) if it was helpful for you

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for how to convert numbers to string, you can use the `(number->string x)`.

However, since you're looking to have the numbers represented as asterisks, it may be better for you to keep them as numbers until you've constructed a string of asterisks. In that case, you probably want a method like:

```
(define (num-to-asterisks x)
        (make-string x #\*))
```

Comment: How would I approach that? Thanks!

Comment: When I tried to run it to test for x as 1, it gives me an error code of string-append expected a string but instead got a list

Comment: Nevermind I wrote

(define (num-to-asterisks x)
  (cond 
    [(zero? x) ""]
    [else (string-append "*" (num-to-asterisks (sub1 x)))]))

(check-expect (num-to-asterisks 0) "")
(check-expect (num-to-asterisks 2) "**")

But now I have to make it so my code puts it as a descending order. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(define (triangle n)
  (let building ((i 0) (r '()))
    (if (= i n)
        r
        (building (+ i 1)
                  (cons (string-append "*" (if (null? r) "" (car r)))
                         r)))))
```

this is nicely tail-recursive; builds up the result list by adding "*" to the first element of the result list.